# Drupal 6 - Styling page H1 tags

Tags: php, drupal-6

I have my page.tpl.php with a standard h1 tag:

```
<h1><?php print $title ?></h1>
```

All is well with the world, however, I want to use an aimge to style my H1 tags with font. This is all very well but these are all unique so I need to add a class to the h1 tag so that all my main sections are unique.

My thoughts are using php to grab something unique on each main page...the URL is unique so I grab that:

```
<div class="<?php print $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);?>"><h1><?php print $title ?></h1></div>
```

This works fine and I don't even know php! BUT!! Some of my URLs have numbers in them, they are printed fine in the page code but the css will not communicate with them :(

So this is fine:

```
<div class="books-and-toys"><h1><?php print $title ?></h1></div>
```

However, this will not style:

```
<div class="70s-books-and-toys"><h1><?php print $title ?></h1></div>
```

So, does anyone know how I can get round this,or indeed, anything else that is unique about my pages so that I can print something to make the div id?

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

as far as I'm aware, at least as of CSS 2.x, all class names must begin with a `-`, `_` or the letters `a-z`. As a result `70s-` will not be a valid class name.

A quick fix, would be to prefix the class:

```
<div class="<?php print 'title-' . $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);?>">
    <h1><?php print $title ?></h1>
</div>
```

you can also eliminate this extra div by doing:

```
 <h1 class="<?php print 'title-' . $current_path = drupal_get_path_alias($_GET["q"]);?>">
       <?php print $title ?>
 </h1>
```

but the DIV is fine; especially if you want to style contents within it in addition to the header.